# Function in $L^1$ making function in Hardy space

Tags: complex-analysis

The following question is asked in Greene and Krantz, Problem 7, page 413:

> If $f$ is a function in $L^1 (\partial \mathbb{D})$ and $F$ is the function defined on $\mathbb{D}$ by the Cauchy integral formula for $f$, is it true that $F$ is in $H^1$?  If not, what additional assumption will guarantee that $F$ is in $H^1$?

I know that if $f$ is continuous, then $F$ will be holomorphic, but is this true if $f$ is only integrable?

Answer (score 0):

We have $Hf = if - iF$, where $H$ is the Hilbert transform.  So you either need both $f, Hf \in L^1$, or there is an alternative characterization in terms of the maximal function $Mf \in L^1$.